# Ember.js model function, Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am a bit of a newbie to Ember.js and I am having an issue when trying to use the model function within a route.

I have been following the docs on the ember website and so far have the following.

```
App.Latest = DS.Model.extend({
title: DS.attr('string'),
volume: DS.attr('string'),
issue: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Latest.FIXTURES = [{
"title": "test Title",
"volume": "test volume",
"issue": "test issue",
}];

App.LatestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Latest.find();
  }
});
```

This gives me the following in chrome's console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Thanks

EDIT: I am using ember-1.0.0-rc.3 and I have the adapter set up.

FIX: Make sure your not making school boy errors like me and check your ember data is up to date

Answer (score 3):

What revision of ember data are you using? Is your adapter setup properly?
i.e.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

Edit:

Your fixture data needs to have an ID attribute

```
App.Latest.FIXTURES = [{
  "id"    : 1,
  "title" : "test Title",
  "volume": "test volume",
  "issue" : "test issue",
}];
```

http://jsbin.com/odijiq/3/edit working example

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this. Yes my adapter is the same as your example above. and I am using handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3 obtained from the ember starter pack on github

Thanks

Comment: It wasn't the missing id within Fixtures it was the name of the route. So I diff'ed your code to mine and the only difference was the adding the id and your route was named IndexRoute and mine was named LatestRoute.

Adding the id didn't fix it but changing mine to be IndexRoute did fix it. I am not 100% sure yet why this is I will have to do some more reading.

Thanks for the code example it helped a lot.

Comment: For completeness, you could also try adding LOG_TRANSITIONS: true when you create you app as shown here http://jsbin.com/odijiq/4 to track route transitions in the console to help track issues down.

Comment: Just realised what I mentioned earlier yesterday didn't work it just transfered the issue to the index view rather than the latest view.

Comment: Do you have an example where the error is occurring so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I dont right now I am afraid because when i put it on JSBin it just works and not the same as my local copy. I appear to have it all working now so I may just delete this thread as I am not 100% sure what the issue was but I think it was coming form the ember data I was using before

Comment: Are you using RequireJS or some AMD strategy locally? I have had issues in the past with RequireJS and some Ember Data relationships.